# Upload CSV to Heroku via AJAX - Node/Express

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express

I have a database I would like users to be able to update using CSV files. I'm trying to use the Postgres `COPY` function to do this but haven't gotten it to work.

HTML:

```
<h2>Mass Update</h2>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="mass">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="upload"/><br/>
    Replace <input type="checkbox" name="replace"/>
  </form>
<button id="trigger-mass">Submit</button>
```

jQuery

```
$('#trigger-mass').on('click', function(){
var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById('mass'));
$.ajax({
    url: base + table,
    processData:false,
    data:fd,
    type:'POST'
});
```

Node

index.js

```
 app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
 app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:__dirname +'/static/tmp', keepExtensions:true}));
```

This may not seem best practice, but it is ok in my case as I want these uploads to be available for download. I was receiving `Error:ENOENT open"..."` if the `tmp` dir was outside the `static` dir.

routes.js

```
 // Clear table and refill with data
 app.post('/data/:table', auth, function(req, res) {
    var oMsg = quickRes(res, req);
    console.log('REQ DATA')
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);
...// Here is where I would issue the COPY command through pg
 });
```

Unfortunately, I haven't had anything show up in `req.files`.  I've also tried just directly uploading the file in AJAX as `data:document.getElementById('file').files[0]` to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly set `contentType` to `false` in `$.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
  url         : base + table,
  processData : false,
  contentType : false, // <-- required
  data        : fd,
  type        : 'POST'
});
```

Otherwise, jQuery will set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, which isn't appropriate for file uploads.

Comment: This was one part of the problem. I was also getting the `Error: ENOENT open "..."` when bodyParser was trying to store the file in `tmp`. I added the `tmp` directory beneath the `static` directory and it worked. So this was also a permissions issue of my file system. Thanks much.

Comment: Also, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8758614/1149459) may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Could we get a look at the middleware you've included and what version of express you're using? `express.multipart` will be deprecated in the next version so you have to use an alternative solution. The general consensus thus far is to use the `connect-busboy` npm package as a middleware for file uploads.

Example index.js:

```
app.use(express.json()); // These replace the bodyParse middleware due to the tmp folder vulnerability
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(busboy());

app.post('/data/:table', auth, function (req, res) {
    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/tmp/' + filename);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {
            res.redirect('/'); // Or wherever you want to go next
        });
    });
});
```

Included node packages would be `express`, `fs`, and `connect-busboy`. See this [Github Issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1793) to confirm the deprecation of `multipart`.

Comment: That issue doesn't say `bodyParser` will be deprecated, it says [that the `multipart` part of `bodyParser` will be removed from it](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1793#issuecomment-27016607).

Comment: I'm on Express 3.1 and did get it to work using the above suggestion. Good chance I never upgrade bc this is a short term API I'm building. But does this mean that all form uploads to express will have to use another plugin in the future?

Comment: Only for multipart. I guess connect could build in busboy to bodyParser, but it's up to them.

Comment: @Deif I think `express.multipart` will still exist, just as a separate middleware instead of being part of `bodyParser` (so you have to be more explicit if you want your server to support file uploads).

Comment: Yup, but at the moment it references the connect.multipart middleware directly without any other code, so I meant they would either have to wait for connect to update it or write it themselves.